# By using Alamofire, I want to upload a video file

Tags: ios, swift, video, alamofire, alamofireimage

I need to upload a video to server using Alamofire. The user selects the video from device and I get URL in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` successfully as follows:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    let ivHandler = LocalImageVideoHandler()
        
    let videoUrl = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? NSURL?
    let pathString = videoUrl??.filePathURL
    self.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

And then I upload the video using the following code:

```
func uploadPostFiles(imageVideoPath:String,parameters:Parameters) {       
    AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        // Selected Video Path/URL =  "file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/51D56143-9303-407D-8E37-AAC576766407/tmp/trim.59847342-DD95-4B74-A7BE-82BA0F3D706E.mp4"
            
        multipartFormData.append(URL(string: imageVideoPath )!, withName: "file", fileName: "trim.59847342-DD95-4B74-A7BE-82BA0F3D706E.mp4",mimeType: "video/mp4")
            
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            if let temp = value as? String {
                multipartFormData.append(temp.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
        }
    }, to: ApiConstant.BASE_URL+"/upload", method: .post, headers: getHeaders().self)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<500)
        .response { response in
            if response.data != nil&&response.response?.statusCode==200 {
                do {
                    let users = try JSONDecoder().decode(GetPostModel.self
                                                     , from: response.data!)
                    debugPrint(users)
                    if(users.status){
                    }else{
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
            }
        }else{
        }
    }
```

It enters in the failure block, and the following error displays:

The URL provided is a directory:

file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/51D56143-9303-407D-8E37-AAC576766407/tmp/trim.3751F517-4A5D-43C3-B8ED-BC41313653FE.mp4

Comment: `URL(string: imageVideoPath)` with `imageVideoPath` being a file path? That's the wrong `URL` `init` method. You should use `URL(fileURLWithPath: imageVideoPath)` instead.

Comment: Unrelated, but `temp.data(using: .utf8)!` can be written `Data(temp.utf8)` (shorter and no need to force unwrap). Also `catch let error as NSError {`, don't use `NSError` here. Just write `} catch { print("Error with JSONDecoder: \(error)") }` (and print the actual error). And `if response.data != nil` should be `if let data = response.data`, use unwrap.

Comment: I have resolved this issue error in  this like  

let pathString = videoUrl??.filePathURL